# How to Skip Confirmation question in terminal for command - docker system prune -a

Tags: docker

I am giving the command via  shell script for pruning all docker images and containers. So I gave like this way `docker system prune -a -y` So that it will bypass the confirmation question. But I am getting unknown flag. So could you help me how can I pass the Y value for this command

Comment: Always docs of each software are the best to investigate and dig into

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```sh
docker system prune -af

# verbose way
docker system prune --all --force
```

[Relevant docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/#options) for docker system prune. I agree the `-y` would've been more intuitive to make this command work.